# Sprite outline based on light position in UE4

Tags: shaders, lighting, unreal, materials

I have simple sprite (for example black box) and I like to add to it outline (red line on example image) but based on light direction. I know UE4 use deffered renderer, so I cant access to lights, but I can pass informations as params to material (angle, distance, intensity...). But still Im not sure how to compute visible corner which is lit by light.

[image]

Can you please point me how to achieve this effect?
Thank you.